# Filtering a data frame by factors in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
sp <- combn(c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4"),2)
d <- data.frame(t(sp),"freq"=sample(0:100,6))
```

and two factors

```
x1 <- as.factor(c("sp1","sp2"))
x2 <- as.factor(c("sp3","sp4"))
```

I need a dataframe returned containing all possible combinations of `x1` and `x2` and the `freq` from dataframe  `d` associated with this combination.

The returned dataframe would look like this:

```
data.frame("X1" = c("sp1","sp1","sp2","sp2"),
           "X2" = c("sp3","sp4","sp3","sp4"),
           "freq" = c(4,94,46,74))
```

I have tried:

```
sub <- d[d$X1 == x1 & d$X2 == x2,]
```

but get the error

```
Error in Ops.factor(d$X1, x1) : level sets of factors are different
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not make `x1` and `x2` factors. Just use vectors. Use `%in%` for the logical test.

```
sp <- combn(c("sp1","sp2","sp3","sp4"),2)
d <- data.frame(t(sp),"freq"=sample(0:100,6))
x1 <- c("sp1","sp2")
x2 <- c("sp3","sp4")
sub <- d[d$X1 %in% x1 & d$X2 %in% x2,]
```

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there:

```
d[d$X1 %in% x1 & d$X2 %in% x2,]
```