# Function not returning appropriate value when applied to a data.table column while successful on one variable

Tags: r, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filtering a data frame by factors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099179/filtering-a-data-frame-by-factors-in-r)

I wrote a simple function to map a variable against a table and return the value in a corresponding column. The idea is very the same as vlookup in Excel. The function I wrote is the following:

```
ApplyMap <- function(mappingtable,variable){
  if(ncol(mappingtable)!=2){
    "Mapping table needs to have two columns"
  }else{
    names(mappingtable) <- c("col1","col2")
    output <- mappingtable[col1==variable]$col2[1]
    output <- as.character(if(is.na(output)){variable}else{output})
    return(output)
  }
}
```

My map:

```
require(data.table)

mapping <- structure(list(Field1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Amsterdam", 
"Arnhem", "Groningen", "Rotterdam"), class = "factor"), Field2 = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Gelderland", "Groningen", "Noord-Holland", 
"Zuid-Holland"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Field1", "Field2"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f93f1018578>)
```

When I apply this to a simple variable such as:

```
ApplyMap(mapping,"Arnhem")
[1] "Gelderland"
```

or

```
ApplyMap(mapping,"New York")
[1] "New York"
```

it seems to be working fine. However, now I would like to apply it to the following data.table and add another column with the second column in the map where appropriate. The list is the following:

```
list <- structure(list(List = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("Amsterdam", 
"Arnhem", "Groningen", "Haarlem", "Maastricht", "Rotterdam", 
"Utrecht"), class = "factor")), .Names = "List", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I try to do this with the following code:

```
list$Province <- ApplyMap(mapping,list$List)
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work appropriately. Is there anybody who can help me to understand why it is not working correctly? I get the following error message when I execute the line above:

```
Error in Ops.factor(col1, variable) : level sets of factors are different
```

Obvious, I would like to get second column to the table with the values from the second column of the mapping-table.

Comment: It's quite a good question. But "does not seem to work appropriately" isn't too helpful. That means I have to start working on your question before I understand it. And when I execute your code I might not get the same as you, causing confusion and taking longer. If there is an error, include the error message. If it's not the right result, include what you got vs what you expect. That makes it easier to answer, faster.

Comment: Which I found by pasting the error message into the search box.

Comment: But there are 6 questions (other than this one) containing that error message, returned by searching for [\[r\] "level sets of factors are different"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%22level+sets+of+factors+are+different%22). Put quotes around the error message to search for it as a phrase. And start it with [r] to search just in the R tag.